# Program is finished running dropped off bottom

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

I need help with my code in MIPS. Although I have tried again and again, I take as a result program is finished running drop off bottom.

Code:

```
 initialize data
.data
size: .word 10
arr: .word 1,15,0,-3,99,48,-17,-9,20,15
.text
.globl main
main:
la $s0, size # initialize registers
lw $s1, 0($s0) # $s1 = size
ori $s2, $0, 0
ori $s5, $0, 0 # $s5 = i
la $s6, arr # $s6 = &arr

L1:
bge $s5, $s1, DONE 
# <for-body>
lw $s7, 0($s6) # $s7 = arr[i]
addu $s2, $s2, $s7 # sum += arr[i]

UPDATE:  # <update>
addi $s5, $s5, 1 # i++
addi $s6, $s6, 4 # move array pointer
DONE:
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Answer (score 2):

Your loop is incomplete. After the two `addi` lines you have to jump back to L1.